# feching a specific data from sqlite database and show it in list view

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to fetch specific data from Sqlite database and show it to the list but I have a problem to fetch the specific data so please help me I'm newbee in android.
Thanks in advance

This is Activity class :

```
    private ListView obj;   
    DBHelper mydb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);

            mydb = new DBHelper(this);
            ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

            // Adding it to the list view.
            obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
                            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayTask.class);
                            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
            return true;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
            switch(item.getItemId()) 
            { 
                    case R.id.item1: 
                    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                    dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayTask.class);
                    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true; 

                    case R.id.item2: 

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),radioButton.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    default: 
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
            } 
    } 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }
```

This is DBHelper class

```
    public ArrayList getAllCotacts()
    {
            ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
            //hp = new HashMap();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select status from task WHERE status LIKE "Processing%"", null );
            res.moveToFirst();
            while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

                    String Name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TASKS_COLUMN_TITLE));
                    Log.d("DBHelper", Name);

                    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TASKS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
                    res.moveToNext();
            }
            return array_list;
    }
```

Comment: any errors ? if yes post logcat

Comment: What are you looking for? The Query is wrong.

Comment: I just edit your question for indent the code and see you have a curly bracket "}" not wanted and the last line of your Activity class, it may be that... (I remove it in your question)

Comment: what done wrong in this query please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public ArrayList getProcessingCotacts()
   {
  ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
  //hp = new HashMap();
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  String textValue = "Processing";
  String query = "select * from task where status = ?";
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {textValue});

  //Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from task", null );
  res.moveToFirst();
  while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

  array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TASKS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
  res.moveToNext();
  }
   return array_list1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a strange query there. Try to change your query like this `Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select status from task WHERE status LIKE ? " + Processing +", null );`